# Will Linq ToList() generate NEW items?

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a list like this:

```
  List<Food> foods = new List<Food>();
  foods.add(food1);
  foods.add(food2);
  foods.add(food3);
  ....

  foodsNewList = foods.Where("some conditions").ToList();
```

I want to know if `.ToList()` will generate **NEW** items or not?
I mean is reference to previous items in list will be still saved or not?
E.g. if I have

```
food1.Name="test";
```

Will it will cause update of a food in `foodsNewList` or not?

Comment: It will update that list and that item.

Comment: You could easily experiment it by yourself. The elements in the list are the same objects, there is no way the compiler could know in general how to copy them.

Comment: Depends on whether `Food` is a class or a struct. It ought to be a class.

Comment: @HenkHolterman What will happen if it is a class?

Comment: @HenkHolterman In structs they will be passed **by-value** and they will be new copies. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they're a list of classes like 'Food' in your case then they will be references. You can test this with a simple console app like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foodList = new List<Food>
        {
            new Food { Id = 1, Name = "Peach" },
            new Food { Id = 2, Name = "Pear" },
            new Food { Id = 3, Name = "Apple" },
            new Food { Id = 4, Name = "Garlic" },
        };

        var message1 = "entries in foodList: ";
        var message2 = "entries in myNewFoodList: ";

        ShowEntries(message1, foodList);

        //Create new list with references
        var myNewFoodList = foodList.Where(x => x.Id > 1).ToList();

        ShowEntries(message2, myNewFoodList);

        //Update original list item that was also included in the new list
        foodList[1].Id = 7;
        foodList[1].Name = "Pineapple";

        ShowEntries(message1, foodList);
        ShowEntries(message2, myNewFoodList);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void ShowEntries(string message, IList<Food> listOfFoods)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        foreach (var item in listOfFoods)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Id: " + item.Id + ", Name: " + item.Name);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    class Food
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Results show that the updated item in the original list also is shown as updated in the new list:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`foodsNewList` will just have references/pointers to these `Food` objects. Changing a `Food` object will "update" them in the list

Comment: ...assuming that `Food` is a class, and not a struct, of course